# Apache mod_rewrite not doing anything (?)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with Apache's mod_rewrite. One of the things I'm trying to get it to do is hide some of my implementation details, so that, for example, the user sees the URL http://www.mysite.com/login but Apache responds with the page at http://www.mysite.com/doc_root/login.php instead (preferably without showing the user that it's a PHP file or the directory structure). Here's what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.com*
RewriteRule ^/(\w+) /doc_root/$1.php [L]

#Redirect http://www.mysite.com to the login page
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.mysite.com/doc_root/login.php
```

But when I go to http://www.mysite.com/login, I get a 404 error even though the page exists. I clearly don't have a great understanding of how the mod_rewrite conditionals and rules work, so can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I would turn on RewriteLog and set RewriteLogLevel to some high value.

Comment: You'd better ask this on Serverfault.com

Comment: Can't turn on RewriteLog -- hosting service doesn't allow it. Thanks for directing me to serverfault.com, I didn't know about it before.

Answer (score 0):

Take `doc_root` out of all the stuff you have it in. That will give you the result you're asking for. However I'm not sure if it's desired or not. How are you going to force someone to login if they manually type http://www.mysite.com/index.php?

Also if you're trying to force all traffic to SSL it's better to use a second VirtualHost and `Redirect` instead of mod_rewrite. Those are all questions probably better suited for ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

- Unless your site has a bunch of different domain names, and you *only* want mysite.com to do the rewriting, you don't need the RewriteCond.  (Potential problem.  Apache likes to dick around with the domain name unless you set `UseCanonicalName off`.  If the name isn't what it's expecting, the rewrite won't happen.)
- In RewriteCond (and RewriteRule) patterns, `.` matches any character.  Add a backslash before them.  (Minor bug.  Shouldn't cause rewrites to fail, but they would match stuff like "mysite-com" as well.)
- mod_rewrite is actually a URL-to-filename filter.  Though it is often used to rewrite URLs to other URLs, sometimes it will misbehave if what you're rewriting to is a URL and it can't tell.  (Especially if what it's rewriting to would be an alias, or would otherwise not translate directly to a real filename.)  If you add a [PT] flag onto your rule, though, it will consider the rewritten thing a URL and pass it along to the other filters (including the ones that turn URLs into filenames).
- Do you really need "/doc_root"?  The document root should already be set up in Apache using the `DocumentRoot` directive, and shouldn't need to be part of the URL unless you have multiple apps on the same domain (in which case it's the app root; the document root doesn't change).

UPDATE:

- Another thing i just thought about:  Rewrite rules work differently in .htaccess files.  Apache likes to strip off the leading slash.  So you will probably want to get rid of the first slash in your patterns, or at least make it optional (`^/?login` instead of `^/login`).
- `^/?(\w+)` will match /doc_root/login.php, and cause a rewrite to /doc_root/doc_root.php.  You should probably have a $ at the end of your pattern.

Comment: I'm still confused, but I think this was helpful. I got rid of the RewriteCond directive because (for now) I only have one domain that I'm working with.  In terms of mod_rewrite being a URL-to-filename filter: the file that I want the server to respond with is at "/home2/interag6/public_html/doc_root/login.php". Does that mean that my directive should read "RewriteRule ^/login /home2/interag6/public_html/doc_root/login.php"?

Comment: You should be able to do that.  Though if you do, you could use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/doc_root/login.php` instead.  But before you do too much with that, see the update -- i'm so used to having full access to a server, i wasn't thinking about .htaccess peculiarities.